# How to populate a HTML div on click event using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What is the best way of populate a div (or ng-include) with a ready .html template using anuglarjs, ***not using ng-view and routing***?

for ex:

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="" />
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="getTemplate()" value="Get template" />

$scope.getTemplate = function() {
   //Get and..populate template here
}
```

Comment: `ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if`

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <div ng-show="show">Hello</div>
  <button ng-click="showHide()">Boom</button>
</div>



function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.show = true;
    $scope.showHide = function(){
      $scope.show = !$scope.show
    }
}
```

[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23634/)

***Difference* *between*** `ngShow/ngHide` & `ngIf` - `ng-if` will remove elements from DOM. This means that all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost. `ng-show/ng-hide` does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements, also `ng-if` creates a child scope while `ng-show/ng-hide` does not

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to actually explain the difference? Or show code that works for the OP?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-if` or `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-if="templateVisible">
    <ng-include src="" />
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="getTemplate()" value="Get template" />

$scope.getTemplate = function() {
   $scope.templateVisible = true;
}
```

And using `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-show="templateVisible">
    <ng-include src="" />
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="getTemplate()" value="Get template" />

$scope.getTemplate = function() {
   $scope.templateVisible = true;
}
```

The difference between the two is that `ng-if` doesn't populate the DOM, when the condition is false, while `ng-show` does, but marks it as `display: none`.